# Qual é a diferença entre declarações de função (React)?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou aprendendo react e me deparei com esse exemplo (Que funciona normalmente):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Teste.css';

class Teste extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = { message: 'Hello!' };
  }


  handleClick = () => {
    alert(this.state.message);
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Say hello
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Teste;
```

Em resumo é um botão que ao clicar exibe uma mensagem. Mas uma coisa que não entendi é essa declaração do `handleClick`, pois se eu declarar dessa forma:

```
 handleClick () {
    alert(this.state.message);
 }
```

A compilação não dá error, mas ao clicar dá o seguinte erro. Não estou entendo o propósito dessa declaração. Alguém me poderia clarificar esta duvida?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leia o tutorial novamente, me parece que você pulou alguma etapa. É esse? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html

Comment: Sim, estou lendo, mas não estou conseguindo saber a diferençaa entre declarar como `handleClick(){};` e `handleClick = () => {};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

O problema esta relacionado com o escopo do this, quando evento de click é disparado o this representa o button e não o componente Teste.

Como pode ser visto em https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html, uma solução é forçar o bind no constructo de Teste:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { message: 'Hello!' };
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Entendi essa declaração diferente faz exatamente o que a linha que você adicionou fez.